# Must declare the scalar variable "@TEMPLATE_NAME"

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having an error while I try to execute the following code,looked out for similar solutions but cant figure it out.

```
DECLARE @TAB_COL_NAME TABLE(idx int identity(1,1), COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @TEMPLATE_NAME NVARCHAR(50)
SET @TEMPLATE_NAME = 'MYTABLE1'
INSERT INTO @TAB_COL_NAME EXEC('SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '+@TEMPLATE_NAME)
```

Since I saw many saying to use `sp_executesql,` I have tried `sp_executesql`,

```
  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @TEMPLATE_NAM NVARCHAR(50)
  SET @TEMPLATE_NAM = 'MYTABLE1'
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '+ '@TEMPLATE_NAME'
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                   '@TEMPLATE_NAME Nvarchar(50)',
                    @TEMPLATE_NAME = @TEMPLATE_NAM
```

And this gives out the error :`Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.`

What is the correct solution for this?

and can't I achieve this is in `EXEC SQL`?

some reply would be helpful.

Comment: So, you're trying to create and run a stored procedure that will insert in your table `TAB_COL_NAME` information about all the columns for a table you pass as a parameter?

Comment: yes correct :)...that is what am trying to do,it works fine, but when I try to pass the parameter it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to pass variables? In your case you are not bound to do so. Try the following using concatenation:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @TEMPLATE_NAME NVARCHAR(50)
  SET @TEMPLATE_NAME = 'mytable'
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '''+ @TEMPLATE_NAME + ''''
  print @SQL
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

However, if you must parameterise, you can use sp_executesql in the following manner

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @TEMPLATE_NAME NVARCHAR(50)
  SET @TEMPLATE_NAME = 'mytable';
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TEMPLATE_NAME';
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL , N'@TEMPLATE_NAME NVARCHAR(50)',  @TEMPLATE_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks..,So is this the mistake i made? '''?y?can u explain?

Comment: You can also pass parameters, but this is a simpler way to do it. The code I put can also be put in a stored procedure. When you were concatenating the string, you were missing the quotes for the table name.

Comment: Although a harmless query, this is a SQL Injection risk because it is not parametrised, which is the point of sp_executesql

Comment: Andd it does not help OP to understand how he used sp_executesql incorrectly

Comment: Could you please tell me how to parametrise the above query?

Comment: I updated my answer to show both ways, concatenation, and also parameterising the sp_executesql.

Comment: ok,what should i do if i have temp table inside the sp_executesql ?like,eg:EXEC('SELECT * INTO #TEMP_COL_VAL FROM '+ @TEMPLATE_NAME +' WHERE REPORT_NO_DUMMY = '+@REPORT_NO)

Answer (score 1):

Add N to the 2nd parameter of sp_executesql to make the constant nvarchar

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
               N'@TEMPLATE_NAME Nvarchar(50)',
                @TEMPLATE_NAME = @TEMPLATE_NAM
```

Answer (score 1):

While it won't occur in the given example, the method used to execute `sp_executesql` by concatenating strings is subject to sql injection. This answer properly uses parameters.  Parameter 2 defines the parameters you are passing to the string, and 3+ are the parameters you pass.

Also if you have a parameter with a apostrophe in it, then it will fail it the concatenated version:  `SET @TEMPLATE_NAME = '[MYTABLE''1]';`.  Not very realistic in this case, but something to watch out for in general with dynamic sql.

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE @TEMPLATE_NAME NVARCHAR(50);
  SET @TEMPLATE_NAME = 'MYTABLE1';
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TEMPLATE_NAME';
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL , N'@TEMPLATE_NAME NVARCHAR(50)',  @TEMPLATE_NAME;
```

### [Blog: Dynamic SQL & SQL injection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx)

Comment: The current example, was to be placed in a stored procedure. If the stored procedure is called in a paramerized way, SQL injection is not a problem.

Comment: @StephenBorg: You are right, your answer will work, but it is a bad practice to do things that way.  I think its a good thing to show both ways.